# Action of Landweber-Novikov algebra on infinite polynomial ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, hopf-algebras, differential-operators

Denote $\text{Aut}(\hat{{\mathbb A}}^1)$ be the affine group over ${\mathbb Z}$ that sends some ring $R$ to the strict automorphisms of $R[[t]]$, i.e. those of the form $X\mapsto X + r_1 X^2 + r_2 X^3 + ...$ for some $r_i\in R$. As far as I know, the dual Hopf algebra $B$ of ${\mathcal O}(\text{Aut}(\hat{\mathbb A}^1))$ is called the *Landweber-Novikov algebra*. Apart from this algebro-geometric and also the original topological definition in terms of $MU$, it can also be described as a particular algebra of differential operators acting on the infinite polynomial ring ${\mathbb Z}[x_1,x_2,...]$ with all $x_i$ in degree $1$.

**Q:** Is there a way to see the action of $B$ on ${\mathbb Z}[x_1,x_2,...]$ form the above algebro-geometric definition?

Any help and any comment about what I said is highly appreciated -- since I'm quite unfamiliar with the subject, it might well be that I already mixed up some things in what I said above.

Thank you!